# Using Silverstripe Dropzone with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, silverstripe, dropzone.js

I am using the UncleCheese's silverstripe-dropzone module which works perfectly in a standard page, but when using it in a Bootstrap modal, the dropzone and "Browse your Computer" button does not work.

I think that it is related to [Dropzone.js inside Modal does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610744/dropzone-js-inside-modal-does-not-work) but I can't figure out the code to initialize the dropzone.

I am using Silverstripe 3.6.1

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching modal after DropZone has finished initializing. 
Use shown.bs.modal to re-initialize DropZone inside you modal.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.dropzone-holder').each(function () {
       var upload = new UploadInterface(this, Dropzone);
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks although it didn't work (I got a ReferenceError: UploadInterface is not defined) until I manually added /javascript/dropzone.js and /javascript/file_attachment_field.js to the requirements for the top level page rather than relying on Silverstripe to add them to the modal content page.

Comment: sorry I missed that part, I thought you were already adding the js files, great its working.