# Dropzone inside of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, dropzone

I try to initial Dropzone inside of modal (Clarity-UI), but I can't  be initialize.

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/OvrmJr)**

**Notice:** I run modal as manual with this code:

```
   $('.js-upload-file-btn').on('click',function () {
        $(".js-upload-file, .modal-backdrop").addClass("open");
    });

    // close all modal
    $(document).on('click','.modal .close',function () {
        $(".modal, .modal-backdrop").removeClass("open");

    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropzone.js inside Modal does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610744/dropzone-js-inside-modal-does-not-work)

Comment: I change it, but it doesn't work. [https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/bvORYW](https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/bvORYW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just changed your html code to this and this worked :

```
 <!-- Modal Backdrop for all -->
<div class="modal-backdrop" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<!--Modal Create Folder -->
<div class="modal js-upload-file">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <!--<form action="">     // it should remove--> 
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a aria-label="Close" class="close">
                    <clr-icon aria-hidden="true" shape="close"></clr-icon>
                </a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Upload</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="dropzone" action="/" class="dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Save</button>
            </div>
           <!--</form> // it should remove-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Custom changes may be required to get it work properly. You have use two `<form>` tag as nested